# Trying to add object to array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert my image string to an actually image. Which I had put in the `$response` object.

But I want to add it to my `$projects` array, but I don't know how. However I did tried this:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $projects = Project::all();
        foreach ($projects as $key => $value) {

            $response = new \stdClass();
            $response = Response::make($value->image, 200);
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

            $projects[] = $response;
        }

         return view('projects.index', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }
```

But it didn't work, because it didn't put the `$response` object in each project. Here is a picture to show you what I mean:

[image]

In the database you can see that I only have four projects.

[image]

Comment: You're making your array in json format.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to take an image URL and return it as an actual image... why would you push it onto `$projects` and put that in a view  ? ?

Comment: Because I want to loop through $projects. Because each project can has a image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
$projects[] = $response;
```

With this..

```
array_push($projects, $response);
```

You could also do this..

```
$projects[count ($projects)]=$response;
```

Or just..

```
$projects[]=$response;
```

Take your pick...

Answer (score 0):

You can try array_push to add $response in $projects